# switchMaxMin-Java Script

Tags: javascript, html

I have to write a function switchMaxMin(tab, n) that swaps the maximum element with the minimum element in an n-element array tab. We assume that all elements of the array are distinct (i. e. there are not a few maxima or minima). I don't know how to do this
I started to write the code and I came up with this:

```js
var tab = new Array(6, 4, 65, 34, 67, 89, 45, 7, 35, 79, 23, 56, 87, 12, 38, 9);
var min = tab[0];
var max = tab[0];
document.write("Tablica: ");
for (i = 1; i < tab.length; i++) {
  document.write(tab[i] + ", ");
  if (min > tab[i]) {
    min = tab[i];
  }
  if (max < tab[i]) {
    max = tab[i];
  }
}
document.write("<br /><br />Max: " + max);
document.write("<br />Min: " + min);
```

Comment: `for (i = 1;` you should initialise `i` to zero, otherwise you'll always miss the first element in the array. Arrays are zero-indexed.

Comment: This seems correct, as far as I can see. What's the question? If you just want feedback on the code and how to improve it, then you should probably try posting this on [codereview.se]

Comment: @phuzi, no. the first (at index zero) is the start value for min and max. the loop starts on index 1 then.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I missed the initialisation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To swap the elements you have also to store the indices of the max and min elements

```
if (min > tab[i]) {
    min = tab[i];
    minIndex = i;
  }
  if (max < tab[i]) {
    max = tab[i];
    maxIndex = i;
  }
```

Then you can reassign it by a classical swap function

```
function swapper(maxInd, minInd) {
  let temp = tab[maxInd];
  tab[maxInd] = tab[minInd]
  tab[minInd] = temp;
}
```

```js
var tab = new Array(6, 4, 65, 34, 67, 89, 45, 7, 35, 79, 23, 56, 87, 12, 38, 9);
var min = tab[0];
var max = tab[0];
var minIndex = 0;
var maxIndex = 0;
document.write("Tablica: ");
for (let i = 1; i < tab.length; i++) {
  document.write(tab[i] + ", ");
  if (min > tab[i]) {
    min = tab[i];
    minIndex = i;
  }
  if (max < tab[i]) {
    max = tab[i];
    maxIndex = i;
  }
}

swapper(maxIndex, minIndex);

document.write("<br /><br />Max: " + max);
document.write("<br />Min: " + min);

document.write("<br /> After the swap " + tab.join(","));

function swapper(maxInd, minInd) {
  let temp = tab[maxInd];
  tab[maxInd] = tab[minInd]
  tab[minInd] = temp;
}
```

Comment: document.write(tab[i], ",") in the for loop doesnt make sense when it is going to be checked after that. Yes but the code is correct and I give +1 for that.

Comment: @Dharmindar I think OP's intention was to print the original array with it.

Answer (score 0):

Just another way to do it, slightly less efficient, but fewer lines of code.

```js
var tab = new Array(6, 4, 65, 34, 67, 89, 45, 7, 35, 79, 23, 56, 87, 12, 38, 9);
var min = Math.min.apply(null,tab);
var minIndex = tab.indexOf(min);
var max = Math.max.apply(null,tab);
var maxIndex = tab.indexOf(max);

var temp = tab[minIndex]
tab[minIndex] = tab[maxIndex]
tab[maxIndex] = temp;

console.log(tab)
```